# How can I use SVG titles as tooltips?

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip

Could you help me with my question. My .svg file is a map with countries. All of the countries have a title. How can I display title as tooltip when I hover it? Look here please: http://bit.ly/1N1RVTn

Comment: If you display SVG via an `<img>` tag it's not interactive and doesn't support tooltips.

Comment: @RobertLongson I need to use SVG as background-image? Or how I can do it?

Comment: You can't if it's a background-image.

Comment: @RobertLongson, ok, how can I do it?

Comment: `<object>` tag or `<iframe>` tag instead of `<img>` and then `<title>` child elements in the SVG for tooltips.